# Socrata SODA query search for multiple terms with OR operator

Tags: sql, socrata, soda

I would like to achieve an 'OR' operator search within a Socrata query.  The [Socrata docs](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/queries/q.html) have an example with a single term

`https://soda.demo.socrata.com/resource/4tka-6guv.json?$q=Islands`

The docs further explain that the AND is assumed if there are multiple terms.

> Multiple search terms are ANDed together, rather than used as a phrase search

My question is how can I, if at all, achieve an OR operator.

My exploration so far

```
r = requests.get('https://soda.demo.socrata.com/resource/4tka-6guv.json?$q=BRITISH').json()
print('british',len(r))

r = requests.get('https://soda.demo.socrata.com/resource/4tka-6guv.json?$q=ISLANDS').json()
print('islands',len(r))

r = requests.get('https://soda.demo.socrata.com/resource/4tka-6guv.json?$q=ISLANDS OR BRITISH').json()
print('or',len(r))

r = requests.get('https://soda.demo.socrata.com/resource/4tka-6guv.json?$q=ISLANDS AND BRITISH').json()
print('and',len(r))

r = requests.get('https://soda.demo.socrata.com/resource/4tka-6guv.json?$q=ISLANDS BRITISH').json()
print('no operator',len(r))
```

The output:
`british 72 islands 385 or 66 and 66 no operator 66`

So what I've learned is the AND operator is implied by multiple terms.  Is it possible to search multiple terms inclusive as in an OR operator?  I could do a 'WHERE' SQL type search, but I would prefer to search across fields without specifying the field names, as I may not know them in advance if I batch records.